# angular 7 + html 5 - disabled datalist

Tags: angular, typescript

I worked with `datalist` in my angular project, i want to disable it. I used `[disabled]="true"` but it didn't work

```
<input list="rateValueList" type="text" name="rateValue" formControlName='proposedRate' [disabled]="true"/>
<datalist id="rateValueList">
  <select>
    <option *ngFor="let rateValue of proposedRates" [value]="rateValue.name"></option>
  </select>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Do you want a simple input if datalist is disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Boiled your code down to that and [disable] worked for the  with my chrome (Version 67.0.3396.87):

Template:

```html
<input list="browsers" name="rateValue" [disabled]="false">

<datalist id="browsers">
    <select>
        <option *ngFor="let rateValue of proposedRates" [value]="rateValue.name"></option>
    </select>
</datalist>
```

Controller:

```html
...
  public proposedRates = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}];
...
```

What is your exact error message?